# Angular2 and Node : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: node.js, angular, http-headers, content-type, angular2-http

I have the following method for `http` in angular 2 with header set with `{"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization':this.authToken}`

```
public allJobsStageWidget1= (): Observable<WidgetModel[]> => {
    let widget1Url=  this._configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + 'getAllJobsStagesCount';
    return this._http.get(widget1Url,new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization':this.authToken})
    }))
      .map((response: Response) => {console.log(response.json());response.json() })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

and in my node application, the following things are done:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization ,Accept');
   next();
});
```

When I make a `GET` request, then `'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rest-0023:3000/api/getAllJobsStagesCount. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403'` error is thrown, as I have already set all headers. But I don't know exactly where I am missing things.

Comment: I had same problem. did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't declined an authorization method. I think header line should look like this:

```
headers: new Headers({
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "Basic " + this.authToken
})
```